# I want to show the taxonomy data on my custom template page in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy, custom-taxonomy

I want to show the `Taxonomy` data on my **Custom Template Page**.

I use `get_object_texonomies()` function but I m getting full array of taxonomy.

Answer (score 0):

Replace **$type** according to your taxonomy type.

```
<?php
$type = 'products';
$args=array(
  'post_type' => $type,
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'caller_get_posts'=> 1

$my_query = null;
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
  while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
    <p><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
    <?php
  endwhile;
}
wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post().
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use similar to this:**

```
<?php 

   $taxonomy_objects = get_object_taxonomies( 'products', 'sports' );
   print_r( $taxonomy_objects);

?>
```

**Reference:**

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_object_taxonomies